# How to reformat the output from iexfinance stock.get_financials(). The current output is a 3D nested dictionary, not a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As per the documentation (https://addisonlynch.github.io/iexfinance/stable/) the default output for the endpoint get requests are dataframes.
However the following sample code returns a nested dictionary (2x1x70)

```
    from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
    stocks=Stock(['NEM','FCX'],token='my_live_token',output_format='pandas')
    fins_data=stocks.get_financials(period='annual') 
    print(fins_data)
```

Is this a standard nested dictionary?
The target output should be a dataframe of two rows indexed on the first keys (which are stock tickers, in this case 'NEM' and 'FCX'). The other text from the dictionary output are the column headings (it appears there is no heading for the ticker as this is the index/key).

I would expect the same format to that which you get when you run the following:

```
    from iexfinance.stocks import Stock
    stocks=Stock(['NEM','FCX'],token='my_live_token')
    co_info=stocks.get_company()
    print(co_info)
```

Any ideas how to convert the output from `get_financials()` to a usable dataframe format??

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following:

```
    fins_dict=stocks.get_financials(period='annual') 
    fins_data = pd.concat(fins_dict, axis=0, keys=fins_dict.keys())
    fins_data.index = fins_data.index.droplevel(1)
    print(type(fins_data))
```

This seems to strip away the outer dictionary and leave the inner dataframe and removes the date index. IEX Cloud have moved there 'financials' data into a times-series library which appears to want to add a time index to everything. Not sure if this is the correct solution as it appears there is still some inconsistency within the data-structures. Any insights appreciated.